# Creating an OGL Window in OSX without using an XIB

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, xib

Is it possible to create an OpenGL Window in OSX using Xcode 4, without using an XIB?

I want this to be a static library, otherwise I'd be happy using the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, you can create all UI elements programmatically. You simply create a window with `NSOpenGLView` content, for example:

```
NSWindow *w = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100,100,400,300)
                                          styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask
                                            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                              defer:YES];
NSRect frame = [w contentRectForFrameRect:[w frame]];
// this is optional - request accelerated context
unsigned int attrs[] = { NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated, 0 };
NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:(NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute*)attrs];
NSOpenGLView  *view = [[NSOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:frame pixelFormat:pixelFormat];
[pixelFormat release];
// manage properties of the window as you please ...
[w setOpaque:YES];
[w setContentView:view];
[w makeFirstResponder:view];
[w setContentMinSize:NSMakeSize(150.0, 100.0)];
[w makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
```

In practice you'll probably subclass `NSOpenGLView` and use your class instead...

Comment: It's really hard to find an up to date guide, but this has worked beautifully, thank you Simon!